# Failing to Understand ssl_opts in Elixir Phoenix Ecto's Postgres Adapter

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, tls1.3

So I have installed the Percona Postgres Operator and Distribution on Kubernetes. Everything works fine, I can do the check mentioned on their installation [site](https://docs.percona.com/percona-operator-for-postgresql/TLS.html#check-connectivity-to-the-cluster) by using the ssl certificate generated in the helm install process.
In my runtime.exs, I have this configuration for postgres:

```
config :core, Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("POSTGRES_USERNAME"),
  password: System.get_env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
  database: System.get_env("POSTGRES_DB"),
  hostname: System.get_env("POSTGRES_HOST"),
  ssl_opts: [verify: :verify_peer, cacertfile: "./ca.crt",versions: [:"tlsv1.3"]],
  ssl: true,
  pool_size: 10
```

When I try to do `mix ecto.create`, I get error:

```
08:47:41.422 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.2436.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) ssl connect: TLS client: In state wait_cert at ssl_handshake.erl:2071 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Bad Certificate
```

Obviously, if I do verify: :verify_none, it works like a charm, but then I can put anything as the cacert and it works. I don't understand this as this certificate works with the psql protocol. Can anyone explain this behavior and maybe think of a solution?

P.S.: I tried to add the ca.crt to the trusted certificates, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The ca.crt has to be from the CA that signed the Postgres cert. You should be using the cert in the <cluster_name>-ssl-ca secret.